# ¿A que se refiere "Apply rename on Comments" cuando renombras una clase en Java?

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy modificando el nombre de una clase, esta me arroja un "Cannot Find Symbol" cuando ejecuto el proyecto, si alguien me explicara si existe alguna diferencia entre tener el checkBox seleccionado y no tenerlo a la hora de modificar el nombre de la clase y si tiene que ver con el error que me marca.

[image: Apply]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La traducciones es literal

Cuando se encuentre ese nombre de clase en comentarios los **cambiara por el nuevo nombre** en los comentarios de código

Por ejemplo

```
/***
 * MiViejaClase es una utileria de funciones de prueba
 * @author x
 * 09/11/2016
 */
public class MiViejaClase {
....
```

-> Renombrar a NuevaClase **con** la opción activada

```
/***
 * NuevaClase es una utileria de funciones de prueba
 * @author x
 * 09/11/2016
 */
public class NuevaClase {
....
```

-> Renombrar a NuevaClase **sin** la opción activada

```
/***
 * MiViejaClase es una utileria de funciones de prueba
 * @author x
 * 09/11/2016
 */
public class NuevaClase {
....
```

Seria recomdable simpre que se quiera renombrar una clase, activar esta opción, para mantener el código y los comentarios correlacionados